# action events for buttons in javafx not working

Tags: java, button, javafx, event-handling

Im making an application in javafx that us an inventory subsystem to allow a user to add to a database or look up a product. The problem I am having is when I click on the next menu, for example if i choose to lookupitem and then i go back to the main menu. the setonaction methods stop working.

```
private void mainMenu() {

    pane.setBottom(null);
    Label mainMenuTitle=new Label("Inventory Subsystem");

    VBox titleBox=new VBox(mainMenuTitle);

    pane.setTop(titleBox);

    lookUpItem=new Button("Look Up Item");
    enterItem=new Button("Enter Item");
    deleteItem=new Button("Delete Item");


    VBox mainMenuChoices=new VBox(20,lookUpItem,enterItem,deleteItem);
    mainMenuChoices.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    pane.setCenter(mainMenuChoices);
```

Above is my main menu and from there it has buttons that let me choose the next screen.

```
private void lookUpItemScreen() {

    GridPane gridpane=new GridPane();
    Button submit=new Button("Submit");
    Button back=new Button("Back");
    HBox submitbox=new HBox(5,submit,back);
    submitbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    submitbox.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,10,0));

    Label Title=new Label("Look Up Item");
    VBox titleBox=new VBox(Title);

    Label idLabel=new Label("Id: ");
    Label productIdLabel=new Label("Product Id: ");
    Label orLabel=new Label("or");

    TextField id=new TextField();
    TextField productID=new TextField();

    gridpane.add(idLabel,0,1);
    gridpane.add(id,3,1);
    gridpane.add(orLabel,2,2);
    gridpane.add(productIdLabel,0,3);
    gridpane.add(productID,3,3);

    gridpane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    gridpane.setHgap(5);
    gridpane.setVgap(10);

    pane.setTop(titleBox);
    pane.setCenter(gridpane);
    pane.setBottom(submitbox);

    submit.setOnAction(event -> {
        //This is wher it looks up item in database and shows data
    });

    back.setOnAction(event -> {
        mainMenu();
    });


}
```

these are both in my start method and the lookupitemscreen is chosen when lookUpItem.setOnAction(event-> { lookUpItemScreen()});

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    mainMenu();

    lookUpItem.setOnAction(event ->
    {
        lookUpItemScreen();
    });

    enterItem.setOnAction(event -> {
        enterItemScreen();

    });

    deleteItem.setOnAction(event -> {
        deleteItemScreen();
    });

    Scene supplierInfoSubsys=new Scene(pane, 640,400);
    primaryStage.setScene(supplierInfoSubsys);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: Where in your code is `lookUpItem.setOnAction(event-> { lookUpItemScreen()});` used? Also I recommend removing unnecessary stuff from your code before posting it in the question. All those layout/style properties are probably irrelevant to the problem. Removing the code setting those properties helps us focus on the actual problem.

Comment: @fabian mkay, I updated it of where it is and deleted some of the unnecesary stuff. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to put:

```
lookUpItem.setOnAction(event ->
{
    lookUpItemScreen();
});

enterItem.setOnAction(event -> {
    enterItemScreen();

});

deleteItem.setOnAction(event -> {
    deleteItemScreen();
});
```

into the mainmenu method and not the start method.